# How to unit test this function?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, async-await, graphql

I am trying to write unit testing for the following code:

This is my logic

```
public async Task RemoveUser(string id)
{
    var response = await _graphQLClient.SendMutationAsync<Response>(request);
    if (response.Errors != null)
    {
         throw new ClientException(errorMessages);
    }
}
```

This is my unit testing

```
[Test]
public void RemoveUser_ShouldCancelUserOnSucessfulRemoval()
{
     _mockGraphQLClient
                .Setup(client => client.SendMutationAsync<object>(It.IsAny<GraphQLRequest>(), It.Is<CancellationToken>(token => token == default)))
                .ReturnsAsync( new GraphQLResponse<object>());

     var psClient = new PsClient(_mockGraphQLClient.Object);
     var removeUserResults = psClient.RemoveUser(id);
     Assert.AreEqual(removeUserResults, /* what to put here? */ );
}
```

I am confused with what should I compare my results?

And how to handle:

> <System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult]

?

Comment: Fedrick; why dit you remove most of your question? As it is now, the quality s very low and unlikely to help others. The code initially provided gave more context for others to relate to their own question.

Comment: I reverted your edits in favor to salvage the question and maintain its quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using async Tasks in your unit test, it's best to make your test function a Task as well.

Luckely the framework supports this.

Adding `async` will give you the benifit of `await` as well.

```
public async Task RemoveUser_ShouldCancelUserOnSucessfulRemoval()
{
   //...

   await psClient.RemoveUser(id);
   //nothing thrown, all okay --- not really the best test case
}
```

Normally you would assert some response:

```
public async Task RemoveUser_ShouldCancelUserOnSucessfulRemoval()
{
   //...

   var result = await psClient.RemoveUser(id);

   //Assert(result);
}
```

Or more integration style;

```
public async Task RemoveUser_ShouldCancelUserOnSucessfulRemoval()
{
   //...

   var removeResult = await psClient.RemoveUser(id);

   var queryResult = await psClient.GetUser(id);

   //assert user is gone
}
```

Comment: If I do that It is throwing an error that cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable.

Comment: Ah, sorry, your RemoveUserId is not returning anything. What outcome do you want to test?

Comment: If you want to test there are no exceptions, above code will work. You'll be `await`ing the call, and any exception thrown will fail your test. To test if the user is deleted, you'll need to compare the data set. Thats a bit more complicated.

Comment: @Fedrick, asserting is no different in an async test method versus a void method. Await the task as Stefan said, do your asserts as you normally would. Literally the only difference is making the method "async Task" instead of void and awaiting the result when you invoke the method under test. The rest of the code should be very much the same. Also, if your test case is that you don't get an exception, then you do not assert. You just let it run (`MethodUnderTest_RegularScenario_NoExceptions()`).. But if there is an output to your method, you write tests that assert against what the output is.